# Why did Moshe complain about the Spies in Bamidbar if he thought it was a good idea?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, parshat-devarim, meraglim-spies

The Posuk ([Deut 1, 23](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.1.23?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)) says:

> ,וַיִּיטַב בְּעֵינַי, הַדָּבָר
>   .וָאֶקַּח מִכֶּם שְׁנֵים עָשָׂר אֲנָשִׁים, אִישׁ אֶחָד לַשָּׁבֶט
>
> [Moses replied to people's offer] *It was good in my eyes*...

What was Moshe's complaint if it was good in his eyes that they offered to spy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rashi answers with an example:

Someone was selling a donkey. The buyer wanted to test the man to see whether the animal was in good health. He asked him for a test drive. The seller agreed, and now the buyer knew that it was in good health, but he wanted to really make sure. He then asked “How about the mountains? Can I take it there?” The seller quickly answered Yes. The buyer now understood that if the seller was willing to allow the donkey to be tested in such a strenuous manner, it must be a healthy animal, so he bought it.

This should also have been the response of Klal Yisroel. You want to know about the land? Fine, Hashem will allow you to spy it out. This was good in Moshe’s eyes: now take his word, and make the purchase. However, they did not. They wanted to see it for themselves. And hence Moshe chastised them.

Comment: Looks like someone is just posting Rashis in Q&A format as they are maavir sedrah each day.

Comment: YOu have to admit its a good drush though

Comment: Rashi's answer is a sort of דחאו בקש (a weak excuse). Moses did act as if he liked the idea. After they didn't step back he was expected to slow them down or avert altogether, instead, he proceeds freely.

Comment: So you're saying, Moses was lying. That he didn't mean to say ויטב בעיניי.

Comment: @al it would be quite a surprise if simchas torah answers your query as he hasn't been on this website since 2011 8 years ago

Comment: @user15464 Can I see how active he is? Besides, that's my comments for the readers also.

Comment: @AlBerko see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/87/simchastorah where on the right it says that he was last seen  in 2011