# Contradiction in the idea of sending spies

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-shelach, meraglim-spies

Currently, I'm presented with two views on the purpose of sending spies - some commentators say that the purpose was strictly military (to learn the strategy), and some say to probe the land's resources.

It seems that both contradict the already established premises, by G-d and Moses and make Moses' approval questionable and surely provoke G-d's rage:

- **If the purpose was strategic**, that contradict G-d's promise of "ה' יִלָּחֵם לָכֶם וְאַתֶּם תַּחֲרִישׁוּן" (Ex 14,14). They should have trusted this attitude as it worked already a couple of times. So, seemingly, Moses couldn't favor this idea. (*see Malbim, for example, that they were not supposed to touch their enemies at all.*)
- **If the purpose was to probe the quality of the land**, that would contradict G-d (and Moses') promise that the land is good. So that way could also be interpreted as mistrust.

How do the interpreters solve those contradictions?

Comment: Wasn’t that one of the problems (according to some meforshim) which is why later moshe chastises the Jews for asking for spies?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why did Moshe complain about the Spies in Bamidbar if he thought it was a good idea?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2120/why-did-moshe-complain-about-the-spies-in-bamidbar-if-he-thought-it-was-a-good-i)

Comment: @DonielF I don't understand where is the connection between the questions? Your question is about Moses' changing attitude, my question is about the whole idea that seems illogical.

Answer (score 2):

Rav Hirsch says that the initial request was (as I say in [Did G-d command or not on sending the spies?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105062/did-g-d-command-or-not-on-sending-the-spies)) presented in order to follow the idea that the Bnai Yisrael would have to start living a *normal* life. This is based on the way Rav Hirsch explains לחפור את הארץ.

Rav Hirsch also points out that they were to then to see which parts were most appropriate for each tribe to settle based on the various characteristics of the tribes and put the military aspect in the background.

> By the order: ויתרו את הארץ the mission received a somewhat different
>   and extended task. It was no longer just to spy out the most suitable
>   way to conquer the land. That purpose was to be in the background, and
>   the task set was to learn to know the land itself as a base for national
>   development and the significant indication was given to consider it
>   from two points of view, as ארץ כנען אשר אני נתן לבני ישראל it is at
>   the present ארץ כנען, the land of a most degenerate nation, and it is
>   the land was given by Hashem to the Children of Israel for them to develop
>   in it a national life according to His revealed Will, the Torah.

Comment: The very first assumption is [seemingly] innately false - if Moses entered Israel and immediately built the Temple (and was the Messiah) I doubt it could be called "normal life". Anyways everything is supposed to follow G-d and Moses' word, just as they followed blindly from the Exodus. What happened suddenly they need to research?

Comment: They had already been told that miraculous life was only in the desert. In the land was to be more *normal* @AlBerko

Comment: who said the manna is gonna end?

Comment: The manna was sent only to be during the time of traveling in the desert. The commentators give the fact that the Bnai Yisrael would have to live a *normal* life once they entered the land as one of the reasons the meraglim tried to stop the entry. @AlBerko

Comment: Where did G-d say that Manna will ever end?

Comment: *"each tribe to settle"* - wasn't it set by lot?

Comment: That was at the end. However, originally, they would have been allowed to request the area that was most appropriate for the individual character of the tribe. Alternatively, they would have seen the character of the individual portions so that they would know what to do when Hashem assigned them. @AlBerko